# Carousel Jquery/Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have been using [this](http://www.bkosborne.com/jquery-waterwheel-carousel/options) carousel to load images dynamically in my homework project of ASP .NET. 
In the documentation of this carousel , there is an option called "activeClassName" which is used to get the center item (if I have interpreted it correctly) but still I am unable to get this class in my ASPX file where I have written my javascript code since I am new to Jquery as well as javascript. I have searched through net and still I could get as far as making an object of a class like this:

```
a = new classA;
```

Can somebody give me any example of how to use this option please?

Comment: Cliche or not... I am eager to learn something new and would be glad if you helped.. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you read the comment in the following code (from the site you linked)

```
$("#waterwheelCarousel").waterwheelCarousel({
     // include options like this:
     // (use quotes only for string values, and no trailing comma after last option)
     // option: value,
     // option: value
 });
```

They tell you how to do it :)

So basically,

```
$("#waterwheelCarousel").waterwheelCarousel({
     activeClassName: 'yourclassname'
 });
```

will do the trick.

Comment: I know to write the class name which I want in the js file but I need to access this class in my view file in which i have linked this js file .... Could you tell me how can i do that?

Comment: You would then find the current item with jquery using `var currentItem = $(".yourclassname');`